# Is it possible to remove the 'name' from the list view of a custom object?

Tags: custom-object, list-view

I have a custom object, HeddyImports, which is linked to Account records. That is, Account is the parent of HeddyImports. When I go to a page to see an Account, the if I scroll down, I see a list of HeddyImport records that are linked to this Account. However, two fields are shown, the "name" and the "title":

```
Edit | Del  a0341000002tsTl Competitor : Minted LLC
Edit | Del  a0341000002tsTo Investor: Technology Crossover Ventures
```

The "name" field looks horrible. I think the values are autogenerated by Salesforce? Can I keep the "name" field from appearing in this list?

Comment: Name does not have to be an autogenerated value it can be set as a Text string of 80 characters when the object is created or modified so it can contain a value that is clear to the business. However I would be careful about changing it when the object is already in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the name cannot be removed from the related list (using standard UI). It is used to access the record (link)

Comment: I found a workaround (or hack) for this...
I manually removed the Name field from the relatedLists element in the page Layout .xml and deployed to my Org.  
Nothing blew up and the Name was removed

Comment: @JeffCallahan thanks for the tip. Was able to easily just edit the page layout xml, redeploy and all is well. Def helpful for Work Order Lines on the Field Service mobile app.